# Microsoft Docsの文章：C#についての文章の引用元が分からない

Tags: c#

Microsoft Docsで以下のページを見つけました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/cc440974(v=msdn.10)
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/cc406725(v=msdn.10)
2001年頃に出版されたようなのですが、この文章の書名をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

矢島聡 著 [C# プログラミングリファレンス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/cc440970(v=msdn.10))というものみたいです。